# A TV and two monitors on one PC solution

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, dvi, analog

Currently I have two monitors attached to my GPU:

- 1x 1080p/144hz TN - (GPU) DVI-D -> (Monitor) DVI-D
- 1x 1080p/ 60hz TN - (GPU) DVI -> (Monitor) VGA

These monitors are set to Expand in Windows.

Now I would like to plug in a TV in the HDMI as well. But this poses the a problem: Games start on the 144hz monitor (as it is monitor #1 in Windows).

There are a bunch of problems with this however:

1. I heard games will pick the refresh rate of monitor #1 when using V-Sync (Causing tearing on the TV).
2. Games will start on the 144hz monitor by default.
3. When the TV is turned off Windows still "Sees" it, making it possible for my mouse to go ~1920 pixels more to left. When it is off I don't want the "Workspace". As the TV isn't for working.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have three monitors and a projector connected to my PC. How I have it set up is I have the side monitors extending the display and the projector duplicating the middle display. This fixes having games start on the wrong monitor and with having a mystery display that you can't see. Plus you can switch between the two without having to restart the game.

I'm not sure about refresh rate though, all my displays are at 60Hz. If it's possible what you could try is setting your monitor to 120Hz, that should help with any tearing that would happen... or disable V-Sync.

FYI, As you may have noticed already, you'll have to manually switch the audio in Windows to the correct destination in this setup.